# Attempt to get numbers instead of NaN values when printing

Tags: printing, octave, binomial-cdf

I've a simple program with a for loop where i calculate some value that I print to the screen, but only the first value is printed, the rest is just NaN values. Is there any way to fix this? I suppose the numbers might have a lot of decimals thus the NaN issue.

Output from program:

```
0.18410
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
```

etc.

This is the code, maybe it helps:

```
for i=1:30
    t = (100*i)*1.1*0.5;
    b = factorial(round(100*i)) / (factorial(round((100*i)-t)) * factorial(round(t)));

    % binomial distribution
    d = b * 0.5^(t) * 0.5^(100*i-(t));

    % cumulative 
    p = binocdf(1.1 * (100*i) * 0.5,100*i,0.5);

    % >=  AT LEAST
    result = 1-p + d;
    disp(result);
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the calculation of the fraction yourself.
Therefore you need to calculate $d$ directly. Then you can get all values of the numerators and the denominators and multiply them by hand and make sure that the result will not get too big. The following code is poorly in terms of speed and memory, but it may be a good start:

```
for i=1:30
t = (55*i);
b = factorial(100*i) / (factorial(100*i-t) * factorial(t));

% binomial distribution
d = b * 0.5^(t) * 0.5^(100*i-(t));

numerators = 1:(100*i);
denominators = [1:(100*i-t),1:55*i,ones(1,100*i)*2];
value = 1;
while length(numerators) > 0 || length(denominators) > 0
    if length(numerators) == 0 
        value = value/denominators(1);
        denominators(1) = [];
    elseif length(denominators) == 0
        value = value* numerators(1);
        numerators(1) = [];
    elseif value > 10000
        value = value/denominators(1);
        denominators(1) = [];
    else
        value = value* numerators(1);
        numerators(1) = [];
    end
end

% cumulative 
p = binocdf(1.1 * (100*i) * 0.5,100*i,0.5);

% >=  AT LEAST
result = 1-p + value;
disp(result);
end
```

output:

```
0.1841
0.0895
0.0470
0.0255
0.0142
0.0080
0.0045
...
```

Comment: Good idea, i got another idea as well, instead of calculating the binomial distribution and add this to the result, i can just do 
p = binocdf(t-1,100*i,0.5);
to find the answer that im looking for without having to deal with big numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation of factorial:

> Note that the factorial function grows large quite quickly, and
>   even with double precision values overflow will occur if N > 171.
>   For such cases consider 'gammaln'.

On your second iteration you are already doing `factorial (200)` which returns `Inf` and then `Inf/Inf` returns `NaN`.

Comment: " Return the factorial of n where n is a positive integer. If n is a scalar, this is equivalent to prod (1:n). For vector or matrix arguments, return the factorial of each element in the array. For non-integers see the generalized factorial function gamma. " - This is what i found in the documentation for Octave, but it's true that the number is becoming to big because of factorial and that's why it doesn't print the numbers.